# Python - differentiating an image in the X direction

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this concept for me. I need to create a function that takes a grayscale image (in a numpy array) as an argument and iterates through it pixel by pixel. In the past, I have used np.nditer(image) for this. I need to return an image (in a numpy array) similar to this picture.

[image]

In order to differentiate the image in the X direction, I need to use:
F(x, y) = F(x+1, y) - F(x, y)

As you can see, I need to go column by column while Y remains the same. How would I go about incorporating that into the np.nditer? I should note that I have to iterate, I can't vectorize for this. Also the output will have a width one less than the original since no calculation can be done once the last column is reached.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That seems a sobel x derivative..

Comment: Hi Miki, I think you're right but I can't use any OpenCV functions that do this automatically for me.

Comment: So remove opencv tag

Comment: that makes sense, it's gone

Comment: post also the original image, so we can compare the result with yours. The answer of @Julien seems correct. Probably your equation isn't the right one. Again, it seems a sobel x derivative. If you post the original image I'll check.

Comment: I appreciate it Miki, I believe Julien's answer is basically right as well (except that the output width does not equal one less than the original), this sample I found returns the same image as Julien's code `x_image=np.array(arr[:,1:arr.shape[1]],dtype=float)-arr[:,0:arr.shape[1]-1]` The problem continues to be that I cannot use functions to do all the work (I wish I could), I need to iterate through each pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`numpy.diff(image, axis=0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) does what you want:

```
In [17]: image
Out[17]: 
array([[7, 2, 0, 7, 5],
       [7, 7, 2, 8, 6],
       [2, 6, 4, 0, 7],
       [7, 6, 2, 6, 1],
       [6, 8, 7, 6, 3]])

In [18]: np.diff(image, axis=0)
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  2,  1,  1],
       [-5, -1,  2, -8,  1],
       [ 5,  0, -2,  6, -6],
       [-1,  2,  5,  0,  2]])
```

There are different indexing conventions used in image processing and arrays, so I might have misunderstood the requirement.  If the above computes the difference along the wrong dimension, use `axis=1` instead:

```
In [19]: np.diff(image, axis=1)
Out[19]: 
array([[-5, -2,  7, -2],
       [ 0, -5,  6, -2],
       [ 4, -2, -4,  7],
       [-1, -4,  4, -5],
       [ 2, -1, -1, -3]])
```

Comment: Warren, I appreciate the time you took to answer. However, I can't use a function that eliminates the need to iterate. I need to painfully go pixel by pixel and calculate.

Comment: *Why?*  Is this  a homework assignment or something like that?

Comment: More of a 'something', but yes, I have to take the archaic approach on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you absolutely want to iterate over the pixels? Why not simply using this?

```
h,w = image.shape
dx_image = image[:,1:w-1] - image[:,0:w-2]
```

Comment: Julien, I don't think I absolutely need to iterate over them (it's just all I know, right now). Your code gave me one short of the width I wanted, so I just used a `w = w-1` after `image.shape`. This definitely has me in the right direction, i'm still testing. Thank you much!

Comment: I have to admit that I don't fully understand the logic here. How would I change this to implement going in the Y direction (row by row)?

Comment: The more I look at this working, the more I think I do need to iterate in order to fulfill requirements. I know it's slower, but I need to loop through and essentially perform `image[r,c] = image[r,c+1] - image[r,c]`

Comment: Logic: image[:,1:w] is the image minus the first column, image[:, 0:w-1] minus the last column.

Comment: Thank you Julien, I appreciate you helping me to understand; however, even though the output picture has been altered, it doesn't look like I expected. I could be wrong though.